# Adapt my textview to content of a NSString and add it to a scrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, textview

I have several days with this and zilch've tried everything to try to do anything contentsize and unresponsive as the code I have now no cut lines and empty spaces.

This is my code:

```
UITextView *textArea=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 220, 300)];
textArea.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


[textArea setText:_descripcion];
textArea.editable=NO;
textArea.scrollEnabled=NO;


[self.elscroll addSubview:textArea];

 CGRect frame = textArea.frame;
 frame.size.height = textArea.contentSize.height;
 textArea.frame = frame;
```

Comment: If you need to show text but you don't need it to be scrollable (as you are using already a ScrollView), maybe you could try to use a UILabel instead of a UITextView. To have it with multiple lines, just set the numberoflines value to 0 (to have multiple) and after setting the frame of the UILabel, call the method sizeToFit to make it fit the text. Hope this helps...

Comment: OK, but then there would be a problem, a label is superimposed over the other and I want them to leave just when just putting another UILabel below